# 'Recent Activity' datetime header is wrong

Tags: bug, android-app

I browsed the activities of last year and found that 'April of 2013' is described as 'earlier this month' in the header. This month is 'April,2014'.

Here is screenshot.

[image]

'Recent Activity' list can be found below the profile.

Comment: Could you include a screen shot?

Comment: I added the link

Comment: Repro'd on Nexus 4, Android 4.4.2, App 1.0.30 and viewing your account's recent activity.

Comment: No that question was a possible duplicate of this one. That one was asked on 2014,December. This one had been asked since April. 